# Merging two dataframes with different timestamp (different time interval)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, timestamp

I have two different dataframes.
Df1 has a timestamp of different time intervals like the following

```
time                     sales
2019-01-01 2:00:00       20000 
2019-01-01 2:20:00       15600 
2019-01-01 2:40:00       15444 
...
2019-12-01 3:00:00       13000
2019-12-01 3:30:00         650
```

Df2 has a timestamp of 1 minute time interval like the following

```
time                   ratings
2019-01-01 2:01:00     0.04
2019-01-01 2:02:00     0.04
2019-01-01 2:03:00     0.04
2019-01-01 2:04:00     0.04
...
2019-12-01 3:00:00     0.01
2019-12-02 3:01:00     0.01
```

I would like to merge the two dataframes like the following

```
time                     sales          ratings
2019-01-01 2:00:00       20000          [mean of ratings from 2:00:00 ~2:19:00]
2019-01-01 2:20:00       15600          [mean of ratings from 2:20:00 ~2:39:00]
2019-01-01 2:40:00       15444          [mean of ratings from 2:40:00 ~2:59:00]
```

I would appreciate any help! Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try `pd.cut`:

```
lower_bounds = pd.cut(df2['time'], 
                      bins=list(df1['time']) + [pd.to_datetime('2050-01-01')],
                      right=False, include_lowest=True,
                      labels=df1['time'])

df1['ratings'] = (df2.groupby(lower_bounds)
                  ['rating'].mean()
                  .reindex(df1['time'])
                  .values
                 )
```

Or you can use `merge_asof`:

```
df1['ratings'] = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1.reset_index(),
                               on='time',
                               direction='backward'
                              ).groupby('index')['rating'].mean()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This perfectly solved my problem.